# Dismiss xib and go to a view controller in a tab bar controller app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, xib

In my app I'm using storyboard and XIB files. I created a storyboard using tab bar controller, then by using a button I load a XIB file. Now I want that when I finished operation in XIB file to dismiss this XIB and go to a particular view controller (not the view controller who calls the XIB) embedded in my tab bar controller.
There's a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

`[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>]
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: I will try, the `<#(NSUInteger)#>` it's the index of the view controller I will to show?

Comment: Yes, <#(NSUInteger)#> is the index.

Comment: I will try to do that, just a sec

Comment: It doesn't work... I tried to do so: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: NO completion: nil];` then I insert your second row of code, but it shows me the view controller who calls the XIB file. I guess I should use the `completion:`, but I'm not sure

Comment: Switch: [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];. Works for me, just tried it.

Comment: It doesn't work =.=, it doesn't do nothing, but you have understand that I'm using storyboard and XIB files??